# vpc peering issues between bastion and app server ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, vpc

I have two existing vpc's. One is shared services, and the other is the actual application servers. I have created a peer between the two vpc's, and added routes on each vpc, but still cannot ssh from bastian to app server from the shared services vpc.

Details:

- shared services vpc cidr(172.31.0.0/16)
- - bastian server ip (172.31.5.84)
- - route added to main route table (10.2.0.0/16 -> vpc-peer-id)
- app server vpc cidr (10.2.0.0/16)
- - ec2 subnet instance ip (10.2.60.4)
- - route added to main route table (172.17.0.0/16 -> vpc-peer-id)
- - added sg allow (22 tcp 172.31.0.0/16)
- I also added the same route to the app server subnet but no change.

I am completely stumped atm for how to set this up or even work our where it is blocking. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the SSH attempt hang for a while, or do you get an immediate error message? Hanging indicates that there is a networking issue. Try temporarily opening the App Server SG for SSH (port 22) to `0.0.0.0/0` to see if this fixes anything (but reset it after the test). If that doesn't help, trying to SSH from the _same_ VPC, to make sure the instance is configured correctly. If that doesn't help, try to connect two other resources to test that VPC Peering has been configured correctly.

Comment: * It hangs. 
* I have tried opening the ssh to 0... but still no change. 
* I cannot ssh from the same vpc as its private and not open to outside, unless there is a way to quickly test. 
* Also, ssh does not work to any of the instances as they are all in the same private vpc and part of a cluster.

Not sure what you mean by two other resources though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assist you, I did the following:

- Started with an existing `VPC-A` with CIDR of `172.31.0.0/16`
- Created a new `VPC-B` with CIDR of `10.0.0.0/16`
- Created a **subnet** in `VPC-B` with CIDR of `10.0.0.0/24`
- Launched an Amazon Linux **EC2 instance** in the new subnet in `VPC-B`

  - Inbound **Security Group**: Allow SSH from `172.31.0.0/16`
- Created **Peering connection**:

  - Requester VPC: `VPC-A`
  - Acceptor VPC: `VPC-B`
- **Accepted** peering connection (Did you do this on yours?)
- Configured **Route Tables**:

  - The public Route Table in `VPC-A`: Route `10.0.0.0/16` to `VPC-B`
  - The private Route Table in `VPC-B`: Route `172.31.0.0/16` to `VPC-A`
- Opened an **SSH connection** to an existing instance in `VPC-A`
- From that instance, opened an **SSH connection to the private IP address of the new instance** (`10.0.0.121`)

**Result:** Instantly got a `Permission denied (publickey)` error because I didn't supply the private key. Getting an instant error messaged proved network connectivity (as opposed to hanging, which normally indicates a lack of network connectivity).

I then supplied the correct private key and tried to SSH again.

**Result:** Connected!

The complete flow is:

```
My laptop -> Instance in public subnet of `VPC-A` -> Instance in `VPC-B`
```

This had to use the peering connection because `VPC-B` has no Internet Gateway and I connected via the private IP address of the instance.

So, I recommend that you double-check that you have done each of the above steps to find where your configuration might differ (accepting the peering connection, configuring the security group, etc).

Comment: Your a legend dude. I noticed a typo in one of the cidr ips as i walked though your example.. nice !!